# Counting frequency of occurrence by month-year using python panda

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, group-by

Suppose I have following Data-Series:

```
Date      Category
2014-8    Facebook
2014-8    Vimeo
2014-8    Facebook
2014-8    Facebook
2014-9    Facebook
2014-9    Orkut
2014-9    Facebook
2014-9    Facebook
2014-9    Facebook
...
2014-10    Youtube
2014-10    DailyMotion
2014-10    Facebook
2014-10    Vimeo
2014-10    Facebook
2014-10    Facebook
```

I would like to make a count of each category (Unique Value/Factor in the Time Series) per month and year.

```
Category     Date        Count
Facebook     2014-01     5
             2014-02     6
             2014-03     8
Vimeo        2014-01     3
             2014-02     10
             2014-03     9
youtube      2014-01     13
             2014-02     61
             2014-03     8
```

So, when I call Facebook, I can see how many times facebook occured on each month.

What I tried is:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: '{year}-{month}'.format(year=x.year,
                                                              month=x.month,
                                                              day=x.day))
a = df.groupby(['Category','year-month']).size()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by both Category and Date and then do a count on Date:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Category', 'Date']).Date.count()
Category     Date   
DailyMotion  2014-10    1
Facebook     2014-10    3
             2014-8     3
             2014-9     4
Orkut        2014-9     1
Vimeo        2014-10    1
             2014-8     1
Youtube      2014-10    1
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

To get the monthly totals for a specific category (e.g. 'Facebook'), you first need to filter on the category:

```
>>> df[df.Category == 'Facebook'].groupby(['Category', 'Date']).Date.count()
Category  Date   
Facebook  2014-10    3
          2014-8     3
          2014-9     4
Name: Date, dtype: int6
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i am doing this thing, but how can get the inormation of Facebook or some other variables? I mean I want to call a['Facebook'] so i will get their monthly freequency.

Comment: @VessilliZaytsev See above for expanded response.

Comment: I think, this will help me to solve the situation. Thank you.