# How to count by time frequency using groupby - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to count a frequency of 2 events by the month using 2 columns from my `df`. What I have done so far has counted all events by the unique time which is not efficient enough as there are too many results. I wish to create a graph with the results afterwards.

I've tried adapting my code by the answers on the SO questions:

- [[How to groupby time series by 10 minutes using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147224/how-to-groupby-time-series-by-10-minutes-using-pandas])
- [[Counting frequency of occurrence by month-year using python panda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281861/counting-frequency-of-occurrence-by-month-year-using-python-panda])
- [[Pandas Groupby using time frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489702/pandas-groupby-using-time-frequency])

but can not seem to get the command working when I input `freq='day'` within the `groupby` command.

My code is:

```
print(df.groupby(['Priority', 'Create Time']).Priority.count())
```

which initially produced something like 170000 results in the structure of the following:

```
Priority  Create Time        
1.0       2011-01-01 00:00:00    1
          2011-01-01 00:01:11    1
          2011-01-01 00:02:10    1
                  ...

2.0       2011-01-01 00:01:25    1
          2011-01-01 00:01:35    1
                  ...
```

But now for some reason (I'm using Jupyter Notebook) it only produces:

```
Priority  Create Time        
1.0       2011-01-01 00:00:00    1
          2011-01-01 00:01:11    1
          2011-01-01 00:02:10    1
2.0       2011-01-01 00:01:25    1
          2011-01-01 00:01:35    1
Name: Priority, dtype: int64
```

No idea why the output has changed to only 5 results (maybe I unknowingly changed something).

I would like the results to be in the following format:

```
Priority  month     Count     
1.0       2011-01     a
          2011-02     b
          2011-03     c
                ...

2.0       2011-01     x
          2011-02     y
          2011-03     z
                ...
```

Top points for showing how to change the frequency correctly for other values as well, for example `hour/day/month/year`. With the answers please could you explain what is going on in your code as I am new and learning pandas and wish to understand the process. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is convert datetime column to months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
print(df.groupby(['Priority', df['Create Time'].dt.to_period('m')]).Priority.count())
```

Or use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
print(df.groupby(['Priority', pd.Grouper(key='Create Time', freq='MS')]).Priority.count())
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Create Time':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='10D', periods=10),
                   'Priority':np.random.choice([0,1], size=10)})

print (df)
  Create Time  Priority
0  2019-01-01         0
1  2019-01-11         1
2  2019-01-21         0
3  2019-01-31         0
4  2019-02-10         0
5  2019-02-20         0
6  2019-03-02         0
7  2019-03-12         1
8  2019-03-22         1
9  2019-04-01         0
```

---

```
print(df.groupby(['Priority', df['Create Time'].dt.to_period('m')]).Priority.count())
Priority  Create Time
0         2019-01        3
          2019-02        2
          2019-03        1
          2019-04        1
1         2019-01        1
          2019-03        2
Name: Priority, dtype: int64

print(df.groupby(['Priority', pd.Grouper(key='Create Time', freq='MS')]).Priority.count())
Priority  Create Time
0         2019-01-01     3
          2019-02-01     2
          2019-03-01     1
          2019-04-01     1
1         2019-01-01     1
          2019-03-01     2
Name: Priority, dtype: int64
```

Comment: For the first I'm getting `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period'` andthe second only produces 2 results

Comment: Ok - first one works with `.dt.to_period('m')`. I'm still only getting 2 results though - I'm expecting a lot more. Do you know how to counter this?

Comment: @pragmaticlearner - hmmm, are datetimes like you expected? Because this seems some data related problem.

Comment: I think so...my command when importing the csv file is `df = pd.read_csv('records-for-2011.csv', parse_dates=['Create Time'])`. It was working before with like 170000+ rows however when I started adapting it to get what I wanted it changed somehow. No idea why

Comment: @pragmaticlearner - Code seems good, is possible check if datetimes have more months like 2?

Comment: Yes there are 12 months in the data set. When I type df and run there are 180015 rows